# Networking Issue with libvirt (kvm)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, linux-kvm

I'm running a desktop class computer tower with Ubuntu Server 13.04 (64-bit) installed.  The server is configured with libvirt, and I use virt-manager to control and configure the VMs as well as virsh.  I've been running this setup for a month now, and suddenly I've started experiencing networking issues.  The major problem at hand occurs when I first start the VMs.  When they're started, everything seems to be working fine.  Network ceases to work after a small amount of data is transferred over AFP (using netatalk) or SMB (using samba).  The VMs act like the network cable was unplugged from them.  They will immediately stop responding to anything and everything.  The host machine is still reachable, and I can even control the VM via VNC.  Any suggestions?

Here is a sample config for my Storage VM:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Storage</name>
  <uuid>9f1085d8-afc9-041c-5ed8-9a07f4383418</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-1.4'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Nehalem</model>
    <vendor>Intel</vendor>
    <feature policy='require' name='tm2'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='est'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='monitor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ss'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='dtes64'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='rdtscp'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ht'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ds'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pbe'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdcm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vmx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ds_cpl'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='xtpr'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='acpi'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/Storage.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/sdd'/>
      <target dev='vdd' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/clay/ISOs/Ubuntu13.04Server64.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:d6:30:fd'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' passwd='<redacted>'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% sure that this is caused by the virtio network driver card (which I have found to be completely unreliable). I have now switched all vm's over to e1000 which never fails.

So, change the network section of your config to:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:d6:30:fd'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This comment also assisted me in getting a debian wheezy libvirt+kvm VM to install where it would not connect to the network bridge using virtio.